# Firebase functions app emulator return "Function europe-west1-app does not exist, valid functions are: "

Tags: firebase, express, google-cloud-functions

My firebase functions express app is not allowing me to call it when emulating.

The emulator seems to be running fine:

[image]

The logs in a better format:

```
i  emulators: Starting emulators: functions
⚠  hub: Error when trying to check port 4400 on ::1: Error: listen EADDRNOTAVAIL: address not available ::1:4400
⚠  hub: Port 4400 is available on 127.0.0.1 but not ::1. This may cause issues with some clients.
⚠  hub: If you encounter connectivity issues, consider switching to a different port or explicitly specifying "host": "<ip address>" instead of hostname in firebase.json
⚠  logging: Error when trying to check port 4500 on ::1: Error: listen EADDRNOTAVAIL: address not available ::1:4500
⚠  logging: Port 4500 is available on 127.0.0.1 but not ::1. This may cause issues with some clients.
⚠  logging: If you encounter connectivity issues, consider switching to a different port or explicitly specifying "host": "<ip address>" instead of hostname in firebase.json
⚠  eventarc: Error when trying to check port 9299 on ::1: Error: listen EADDRNOTAVAIL: address not available ::1:9299
⚠  eventarc: Port 9299 is available on 127.0.0.1 but not ::1. This may cause issues with some clients.
⚠  eventarc: If you encounter connectivity issues, consider switching to a different port or explicitly specifying "host": "<ip address>" instead of hostname in firebase.json
⚠  functions: The following emulators are not running, calls to these services from the Functions emulator will affect production: auth, firestore, database, hosting, pubsub, storage
✔  functions: Using node@16 from host.
i  ui: Emulator UI logging to ui-debug.log
i  functions: Watching "/app/functions" for Cloud Functions...
⚠  functions: package.json indicates an outdated version of firebase-functions. Please upgrade using npm install --save firebase-functions@latest in your functions directory.
⚠  functions: Please note that there will be breaking changes when you upgrade.
✔  functions: Loaded functions definitions from source: .
```

The emulator UI:

[image]

The code:

```
import * as functions from "firebase-functions"
import * as admin from "firebase-admin"
import express, { Express } from "express"
const bodyParser = require("body-parser")
const cors = require("cors")
const routes = require("./routes")

if (admin.apps.length === 0) {
    admin.initializeApp()
}

const app: Express = express()

app.use(cors({ origin: true }))
app.use("/api/v2", routes)
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))

exports.app = functions.region("europe-west1").https.onRequest(app)
```

Calling `http://0.0.0.0:8087/MY-PROJECT-NAME/europe-west1/app/api/v2` and any subsquent route produces the error message:

`Function europe-west1-app does not exist, valid functions are:` and then no valid functions.

My emulator is in a docker container with port mappings `8087:8080` (hence the above URL).

I have tried a number of combinations for the endpoint to no avail. I am clearly missing something.

What am I doing wrong?

Routes look like:

```
router.get("/", centre.hello) // This one return a hello string that I've been using to troubleshoot. no luck
router.post("/centre/add", centre.addCentre)
```

Edited to add additional logs as requested

Comment: On a note, the emulator might start but there maybe some problems with the functions. Can you share a complete screenshot that includes the logs above that table?

Comment: @Dharmaraj added the additional logs

Comment: I'm not sure about your firebase-tools version. As per the docs(https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/releases) the latest version of Fiebase-tools is v11.16.0. Can you try to update to the latest version. You can refer to this link for more insights(https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/3031)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm an idiot.

Although I had exported "app" as above, I had not provided an index.ts which I believe firebase needed.

I realised this when I deployed the functions live and the error message was a lot more helpful.

Emulators now work as expected